# Link bugs to Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

As Stack Overflow is great place to solve our mistakes, it is also a great place to point out the libraries bugs.

Some questions on Stack Overflow is about bugs in Microsoft libraries and programs, Google libraries and programs, and a lot others.

So, I suggest that some questions can be labeled as bugs. This label could be managed by the Stack Overflow community itself, and I am sure Stack Overflow can find some great rules to determine the bugs, (for example, if five people reported a question as a Microsoft bug, or a person with golden badge with some technique could manage this tag for the question, as the same logic for closing question, **again for example**).

Why is this helpful?

I think companies and vendors of software will find a good way to see what the biggest problems of their software is and consequently solve them.

For example, I have [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648654/) on Stack Overflow, and I think it is a good example of a bug in Visual Studio (or IIS).

I am open for any suggestions that could enhance this idea more, and make it more helpful.

Comment: see [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/839601)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think we should use the Stack Exchange Q/A platform as a bug report system. It just isn't fit for that.

Bugs should be reported at the source of the bug. Most companies have a good way to register bugs to their software. The problem with using Q/A to do that is that you will eventually get discussions about the bug, possible solutions and workarounds. That format just doesn't fit Q/A.

That said, I don't think having a meta-tag for bugs is what we want. We should have bug-status-* tags too, which makes things more confusing and a source for maintenance.

If you report a bug at the original source, it is of course okay to link both in your Q/A and bug report.